# If I've favourited a question that gets merged (and possibly deleted), please favorite the target question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, bookmarks, merged-questions

I've favourited a few questions that later get closed as duplicates, merged, and eventually deleted. I can find the "better" target question because I can see the deleted question, and find where the content went, but I shouldn't have to rely on this.

Formal specifics:

- If I've favourited a question, and it gets closed as a dupe, please add to my favourites list all the questions that are marked as duplicates
- When it is merged into another question, please add to my favourites list the question it was merged to

Answer (score 4):

The transition of favorites from source to destination has apparently worked just fine for over two years, so I'm marking this completed.

Changing your favorites in response to closing sounds dangerous to me, and not just because there'd have to be a way to revert it if the question was re-opened... Those lists of duplicates can be edited by hand as well, which would be tricky to pick up - of course, visiting the question from your favorites list immediately shows you the list, which you can then peruse at your leisure.

Merging is almost never *reversed*, and there can be only one target - so updating dependencies is a lot cleaner.